# Calculus to convert Y coordinates for purpose of updating bpm in a metronome

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, coordinates, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm in the course of developing a metronome for iPad. I'm using **CGAffineTransformRotate** for the metronomeArm animation, **NSTimer(I'm not interested in great precision)** for sound and a **UIPanGestureRecognizer** for dragging the metronomeWeight on the metronomeArm.[image]

My problem is that I don't know how to update the bpm by dragging the weight using the pan. For now I have this : `metronomeWeight.center.y` is 240 and the default bpm for this position is 80.The weight goes from top 140 to a maximum of 450. I have implemented this method but it is not correct :

```
-(void)updateBPM
    {
        CGFloat weightYPosition = metronomeWeight.center.y;
        NSUInteger newBPM = (weightYPosition/3);
        self.bpm = newBPM;
    }
```

**and the selector for the pan is this :**

```
-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{

    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:metronomeArm];
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:metronomeArm];

    NSLog(@"miscarea pe oy are valoare de: %f", location.y);

    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(metronomeArm.frame.size.width/2, gesture.view.center.y + translation.y );

    if (newCenter.y >= 140 && newCenter.y <= 450) 
{
        gesture.view.center = newCenter;
        [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:metronomeArm];
        [self updateBPMFromWeightLocation];
        tempoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.bpm];
        NSLog(@"metronomeWeight position : %f ",metronomeWeight.center.y);
    }
}
```

The sound and animation update but not as desired, meaning that the lower limit bpm should be 225 and the upper one should be 1. In my case they are 150 and 46 respectively.

My calculations are not good, so it will be fantastic if you can help me solve this problem... I have looked at apple's metronome project for days and can't understand how they do this...

Thanks

**The new updateBPM method thanks to @zimmryan suggestion**

```
-(void)updateBPMFromWeightLocation
{
    CGFloat weightYPosition = metronomeWeight.center.y;
    float lengthInM = ((weightYPosition - 140) * 0.00041333);
    float time = 2 * M_PI * sqrt(lengthInM / 9.8);
    NSUInteger newBPM = floor(60.0 / time);
    self.bpm = newBPM;
}
```

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: @zimmryan Hello and thank you very much for the formula ! I will try it right now , I wasn't at home. I have to modify it a bit because I have a range from 140 to 450(edited my question to reflect this) and I want the default bpm for the base point of 240 to be 80 instead of 120. I will let you know what happened as soon as I implement , thanks again !

Comment: Hope it works, it was a fun one to try and figure out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding of physics and calculus, the equation for the period of a pendulum is T=2pi sqrt(l/g) where T is time in seconds, l is length in meters, and g is gravity.

You are picking a base point of 290 (pixels) and a BPM of 120. A BPM of 120 converts to a period of .5 seconds. So T = .5. Solving the equation you get .062 for l, or 6.2cm.

But your length is not in cm it is in pixels s now you have to convert it. Since your range is from 140 to 350, your zero point is 350. So first you take 350 - 390 to get an offset of 60. Now create your equation of 60pixels * k = .062 so your k = .001033

Your final function should read

```
-(void)updateBPM
{
    CGFloat weightYPosition = metronomeWeight.center.y;
    float lengthInM = ((350 - weightYPosition) * .001033);
    float time = 2 * M_PI * sqrt(lengthInM / 9.8);
    NSUInteger newBPM = floor(60 / time);
    self.bpm = newBPM;
}
```

or

```
-(void)updateBPM
{
    self.bpm = floor(60 / (2 * M_PI * sqrt(((350 - metronomeWeight.center.y) * .001033) / 9.8)));
}
```

Comment: I decided to make the default tempo 120 so my base point will change from 240 to 290 meaning that I get an offset of 150 and so my k will be .00041. I have implemented the method but when I drag the weight everything is inverted : If I drag the weight up, the tempo increases when it should decrease and when I go down the tempo decreases when it should increase and besides this it goes from 225 to 84 instead of 1.

Comment: @QuiBongJin I misunderstood where your pivot point is. Since it is at the bottom I have edited my answer

Comment: @QuiBongJin in iOS/Cocos2d